# Is there an API that will return how many results there are based your query search?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-dsl

Is there an api that returns how many results/logs there are based off your query search? or like a built in feature with NEST that will tell you how many results there is like i.e. `count`? Because I have a NEST query search that will do the following:

```
var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<EsSource>(s => s
                  .Size(3000) // must see about this
                  .Source(src => src.Includes(i => i
                                    .Fields(f => f.timestamp,
                                            fields => fields.messageTemplate,
                                            fields => fields.message)))
                  .Index("customer-simulation-es-app-logs*")
                  .Query(q => +q
                      .DateRange(dr => dr
                          .Field("@timestamp")
                              .GreaterThanOrEquals("2021-06-07T17:13:54.414-05:00")
                              .LessThanOrEquals(DateTime.Now))));
```

but I realized that the search api cannot go past 10,000 results because the array is empty when you paginate beyond 10,000 results.  [search api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/7.13/search.html#search-api-response-body)

*So, if there is an api or a feature that will let you know how much results there is based on your index or if you are doing a monthly query search as I am above; with knowing that number I can then create a forloop to paginate through each of those documents say the first 10,0000 hits I can view then the next iteration for the next 10,000 hits and so on. Hope this makes sense, i'll clarify if needed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an API that will return how many results there are based your query search?

I'm not aware of any ES API that will return an *exact* count. At high values, it becomes very approximate.

> array is empty when you paginate beyond 10,000 results.

First, returning >10k search results is highly unusual. It sounds like you're trying to use ElasticSearch as a database, which you can do for *some* things, but don't go depending on ACID or anything like that.

To page over large result sets in ElasticSearch, create a [point in time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html) and pass that to the [search API with the `search_after` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after).

Comment: I understand! Yes, I am writing  logs to ElasticSearch then reading those logs in my console application and sending them to my database.  Since there is not an API that will tell you the exact number of results there are based off your query, after creating the PIT id and passing that to the search api with the `search_after` parameter, what would be the set number of hits that it returns per paginate? Just want to know since I would like to plan on iterating through the entire search viewing the entire logs. I will upload what I currently have.

Comment: "I'm not aware of any ES API that will return an exact count. At high values, it becomes very approximate." - the **exact** number of documents matching a search query can be retrieved by specifying `track_total_hits=true`. Without this, the count is accurate up to the default (10,000). The `relation` in `hits.total` indicates how the actual count relates to the value returned in the `value` field. See the blog post https://www.elastic.co/blog/faster-retrieval-of-top-hits-in-elasticsearch-with-block-max-wand for more details

Comment: @MarkCo: You can *request* a certain number, but what is returned is up to the cluster. Since you're uploading all of them anyway, the page size doesn't really matter.

Comment: This is good to know. Yes, I was reading up on `track_total_hits=true` and learned that it can only count accurately up to 10,000. So beyond 10,000 that it is safe to assume it is an approximation correct? Reading from this post https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits and from what you are saying as well.

Comment: @StephenCleary Request as in using `.Size()`?

Comment: So when I run the search query I get back `"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2279,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },` the number that value holds is that how many logs that are matching my query search?

Comment: @MarkCo: Yes, request by `size`. And yes, if you get back an `eq` for your hits, then that is the actual value.

Comment: @StephenCleary Ah, I see. So if the `value` is more than 10,000 is it possible that it will return `"eq"`?

Comment: @MarkCo: It's possible, yes. You can't depend on it, though.

Comment: I understand, thank you for the help and clarification!